# Creating a Record-set

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a recordset from a query that i created in Access 2013. I copied the SQL code from the query a used it as string. I keep getting

> Run-time error 3061. Too few parameters. Expected 1.

I tried also to call the saved query and i get the same error. this is what i have:

```
Dim SQLwTRN As String
Dim Db As DAO.Database
Dim RecSet As DAO.Recordset

Set Db = CurrentDb
SQLwTRN = "SELECT Client.ID, Client.FirstName, Client.MiddleInitial, Client.Surname, Client.Address, Client.CellPhoneNumber, Client.EmailAddress, Client.TRN 
FROM Client WHERE (((Client.ID)=[Forms]![frmMember_Lookup]![txtbxMLmemnumber]));"

Debug.Print SQLwTRN

Set RecSet = Db.OpenRecordset(SQLwTRN)

' Debug.Print RecSet   ' <-- this won't work - RecSet is an Object
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL code has no access to the form so you have concatenate the value from this:

```
FROM Client WHERE Client.ID = " & [Forms]![frmMember_Lookup]![txtbxMLmemnumber] & ";"
```

Comment: Thanks! i will try that. is this the same reason i get the error when i call on the saved query?

Comment: No, your original SQL should work fine in a saved query when opened - if the form is open, of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gustav! It's working and my work has progressed.

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered.